# RSelenium rdDriver() Could not open chrome browser

Tags: r, selenium

My code:

```r
driver <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", port=4234L, chromever = "89.0.4389.23")
```

and output:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'blah.blah.blah', ip: '2601:602:9403:400:0:0:0:f690%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

I have also used `chromever="latest"` and tried different ports. The selenium-server-standalone.jar is in the working directory as well as the chromedriver.exe in case that is important.

I have been able to start a selenium server on this port from the command line using the same .jar and .exe files and then tried the code

```r
browser <- remoteDriver(port = 4234L, browserName = "chrome")
browser$open()
```

only to get the error:

```
Selenium message:Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'blah.blah.blah', ip: '2601:602:9403:400:0:0:0:f690%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I feel as if the "Driver info: driver.version: unknown" is the problem, which I think refers to the chromedriver but I'm not sure. I am quite positive that "89.0.4389.23" is my chrome version and that java, selenium, chrome are all very up-to-date versions.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, were you able to find a fix?

Comment: I have the same problem. When looking at the problem that is met by others on the web I have the feeling that this is related to the java version. Here you have java.version: '15.0.2' (and me too, this is java JDK), while what I found on the web was another version 1.8 (SDK) : see e.g. https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/240

Comment: You can try few things, 1. Go to `C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\binman\binman_chromedriver\win32` and delete license file. 2. Install latest `chromedriver`. 3. Update all drivers and packages.